# How to retrieve json data to laravel controller

Tags: angularjs, json, laravel, request

There are questions like this on StackOverflow, that I know.

Trust me, I have tried all the solutions to no avail.

I have been trying to post this json data from angularjs to a laravel controller method:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "add-user",
    "display_name": "Add new user",
    "description": "Create a new worker",
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "add-role",
    "display_name": "Add role",
    "description": "Add user role",
  }
]
```

this is the code that posts this json data to a laravel controller:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url:  '/api/roles/assignPermissions/' + name,
    headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' },
    data: $.param(role_perms)
}).success(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Now in this controller method, I just want retrieve this json data, return it and display it in the console to be sure that I received it in the controller.

Below is the controller and all the attempts I've made to get this json data and return it.

**The controller:**

```
public function massAssignPerms(Request $request, $roleName)
{
    $role = Role::where('name', $roleName)->first();


    // this returned nothing
    return json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true); 

    // this returned: add-user=&add-role=
    return file_get_contents('php://input');

    // returned nothing
    return json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

    // returned empty array []
    return $request->json()->all();
}
```

I am unable to find what's wrong with my code. Or it could be that I'm doing it wrongly?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: Please show result of `dd($request);`

Comment: @jackel414 I am using laravel 5.3

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you're returning your variable with your response. To return JSON from a controller function in Laravel, this is the proper syntax as laid out in [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#json-responses):

```
return response()->json([
    'name' => 'Abigail',
    'state' => 'CA'
]);
```

Assuming you wish to return the result of your roles query, you could do the following. You may also specify a status code if you wish.

```
return response()->json(['role' => $role], 200);
```

EDIT: If you wish to simply return the data from the original request, you can make that the content of the JSON response instead:

```
return response()->json($request->all(), 200);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what you wrote will return a response from json already existing in the controller. What I want to return is the json from the $request that gets passed to the controller.

Comment: what is the result if you do `dd($request->all());` at the top of your controller method?

Answer (score 0):

If the data you showed is really what is sent (I'm guessing you're testing with hardcoded values?) then it's not proper JSON (extra comma after last key of each object).
Try with:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "add-user",
    "display_name": "Add new user",
    "description": "Create a new worker"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "add-role",
    "display_name": "Add role",
    "description": "Add user role"
  }
]
```